# [Asterisk]Attended transfer using hook flash on a SIP channel

Tags: hook, voip, asterisk, transfer

Within our organisation we use quite a few different models of telephone sets. The only thing they have in common, apart from the dialpad, is the ability to "send" hook flash. I prefer using this type of signaling for attended transfers above combinations of the usual dialpad keys to prevent the other end from receiving DTMF-tones (to prevent unwanted interactions with IVRs or bothering people on the other end).

2 questions:

1. How is a flash hook represented in features.conf? According to [RFC2833](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2833.txt) section 3.10 (DTMF Events) and [this article](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Flash) (which is about a ZAP- instead of SIP-configuration, thus my doubt... see next question, also), it should be just "flash".
2. From my Google-quest I've learned that hook flash gets ignored by the PBX when using the SIP-protocol in Asterisk... I do get an error message when sending it: "WARNING[26159]: chan_sip.c:6487 sip_indicate: Don't know how to indicate condition 9". Is there a way to fix it/work around it?

Asterisk version: 1.8.3.2

Using "info" for dtmfmode

Tnx in advance!

Comment: There is now a "Flash" AMI event you could use. I use this to perform all channel manipulation - no DTMF codes in features.conf for me

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you have in you adapter settings what to do with hook. IF you have, you can change that to transfer code.

Update: after code review i can say that DTMF 16 received ok and sended in 1.8.x. BUT features.c have no any action on flash(event 16)
So posible create audiohook application for asterisk to change that DTMF 16 to 2 DTMF values or invoke transfer. Will work for DTMF method SIPInfo, and such patch complexity is below-average(5-6 hours for expert)

Comment: For anyone looking at this now, this capability is now built into Asterisk (Asterisk recognizes flash events and now sends AMI events for them as well)